# Powershell DSC xChrome Sample failing on AzureVM

Tags: powershell, azure, dsc

I'm attempting to run the xChrome sample (https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/DSC-Resource-Kit-All-c449312d) on an Azure VM and it fails to run.  Everything runs and executes, but I receive the error (larger log snippet below):

CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (MSFT_xChrome\MSFT_xChrome:String) [Configuration]

AzureVM is Windows Server 2012 with Powershell Version 5:
$PSVersionTable.PSVersion

Major  Minor  Build  Revision

---

5      0      9883   0
The steps I use to execute are:

1. Download xChrome extension (from above url) and inflate it into my modules directory
2. Publish-AzureVMDscConfiguration  -ConfigurationPath
   C:\Users\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\xChrome\Example\Sample_xChrome.ps1
   -Force
3. Get-AzureVM -ServiceName '' -Name '' |
   Set-AzureVMDscExtension -ConfigurationArchive Sample_xChrome.ps1.zip
   -ConfigurationName Sample_InstallChromeBrowser  -ConfigurationArgument @{Language='en';LocalPath='$env:SystemDrive\Windows\DtlDownloads\GoogleChromeStandaloneEnterprise.msi'} | Update-AzureVM
4. **The error snippet:*
   [2015-04-17T23:35:06] Executing the configuration function to generate the MOF files.
   PSDesiredStateConfiguration\Configuration : The module 'MSFT_xChrome' could not be loaded. For more information, run 'Import-Module MSFT_xChrome'.
   At C:\Packages\Plugins\Microsoft.Powershell.DSC\1.7.0.0\DSCWork\Sample_xChrome.ps1.8\Sample_xChrome.ps1:3 char:1

   - Configuration Sample_InstallChromeBrowser
   - ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   - CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (MSFT_xChrome\MSFT_xChrome:String) [Configuration], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
   - FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotAutoLoadModule,Configuration

[2015-04-17T23:35:08] Removing file lock
C:\Packages\Plugins\Microsoft.Powershell.DSC\1.7.0.0\bin\DscExtensionHandler.ps1 : Error enabling the DSC Extension: Errors occurred while processing configuration 'Sample_InstallChromeBrowser'.
At line:7 char:2
+  C:\Packages\Plugins\Microsoft.Powershell.DSC\1.7.0.0\bin\DscExtensio ...

Comment: Have you posted your question on that gallery entry's [Q&A tab](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/DSC-Resource-Kit-All-c449312d/view/Discussions#content)?

Comment: Have you tried the current module or checked any of the answers?

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this error by changing how I was importing the module.

Import-DscResource -ModuleName xChrome -Name MSFT_xChrome

Answer (score 0):

The error implies that a module could not be loaded. Can you connect to the VM using remote desktop and check if Get-DscResource -Module xChrome lists the resource correctly

Comment: I'll re-confirm in morning and get back to you.  Were you able to get the example to work in azure?